# Change revision parents to remove earlier revisions from history?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert, reparenting

How does one quickly reparent a tree in mercurial such that if this is the original structure:

`A-B-C-D-E-F`

I want to change it to:

`D-E-F` (or even `A-D-E-F` would do)

I tried the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5914840/3021102) with the splicemap but it fails with the error `splice map revision <hash> is not being converted, ignoring'`

It also prints out `abort: no node!`

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you WANT to do it with hg-convert instead of just 'rebase'?

Comment: `convert` also rewrites history, but doesn't eliminate changes; otherwise, future changes may depend on changes that were removed.  Do you want actual removal of changes?

Comment: We cannot understand your question, please be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress away all parents in a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382143/compress-away-all-parents-in-a-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this using the `histedit` extension:

First, let's create a test repo with the structure you want:

```
hg init
echo "a" > file
hg ci -m "a"
echo "b" >> file
hg ci -m "b"
echo "c" >> file
hg ci -m "c"
echo "d" >> file
hg ci -m "d"
echo "e" >> file
hg ci -m "e"
echo "f" >> file
hg ci -m "f"
```

Then, do `hg histedit`, and enter the following selections in your editor:

```
pick e4c09693d7a6 0 a
r 380d6d1ef006 1 b
r 33131e82bb1b 2 c
r pick 9325fb48b48e 3 d
pick 844ebb0b3844 4 e
pick bc85bc9ade8f 5 f
```

That will leave only three commits in the repo.

Note that for this to work the [phase](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/phases) of the commits in your repo must be draft. You also might need to activate the histedit extension, which ships with mercurial.